Usage Count in 24 hours DAX / Power BI
Im trying to establish how many user have used our voice channel in a 24 hour period in Dax. A rudimentary understanding of Dax and a mixture of ChatGPT has gotten so that it counts the number of contact in a full day, and counts each interaction as 1, 2, 3 etc as seen in the picture.
Dax code used and example of data
What i really want is a 24hr period from initial contact which could run over 2 consecutive days, and that if the user has contacted 3 times in a day all 3 records would show as 3 as to not skew data further down the line. I also need to expand into a full 7 day period too if at all possible.
Dax is the best we have as other more efficient languages / programs are locked down on company devices.
Heres the code
EmailSequence = 
VAR CurrentEmail = 'Voice'[User email]
VAR CurrentDateTime = 'Voice'[DateTime]
VAR PeriodStartTime =  Voice[DatePeriod]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Voice'),
    FILTER('Voice', 
    NOT(ISBLANK('Voice'[User email])) &&
    'Voice'[User email] = CurrentEmail &&
    'Voice'[DatePeriod] = PeriodStartTime &&
    'Voice'[DateTime] <= CurrentDateTime
    ))


How would you define "initial contact"? What if a user has been contacted ever hour for 36 hours - which 24 hour period would this be? What is the end goal?

the parameters ive been given are in a 24hr period and in a  7 day period. If it has to be all on the same calendar day then so be it, but ideally if someone were to contact at 12pm on one day and then at 11am the next we'd want these grouped together.
End goal is to establish the number of users causing lots of work into the voice channel so we can create targeted improvement campaigns to reduce the number of call.

If someone were to contact at 12pm in day 1, and 11am in day 2, and 3pm in day 2, and 12pm in day 3 - how would you count these? Over which 24 hour period?

ideally day 1 would commence at 12pm and finish at 11:59 on the next calendar day
it should use the first time found as an initial time, and then 24hrs from there. if they contact again at 12:01 on the next calendar day that  would count as the 2nd day
Its an ideal world senerio to be honest. if i can get it to give the highest count for all rows number in a single calendar day that would be sufficient

Simply drop &&     'Voice'[DateTime] <= CurrentDateTime and it should give you the number per day.

unfortnatley that still gives me the same values not the max number for each day in each record.
So IMS 12345 Count 3
IMS 12356 Count 3
IMS 12876 Count 3
All email addresses are the same and all are on the same calendar day

Isn't that what you wanted? To show 3 in each of those? What do you expect it to have for those three? Or are you wanting the max for a given user of their daily count? Quote all 3 records would show as 3 as to not skew data further down the line

yes thats true, but it didnt seem to work

Try the following two Calculated Columns:
PerDay = 
  var thisEmail = [User email]
  var thisDate = [Date opened]
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Voice'),
      FILTER('Voice', 
        NOT(ISBLANK([User email])) &&
        [User email] = thisEmail &&
        [Date opened] = thisDate
      )
    )



// Mon - Sun
PerWeek = 
  var thisEmail = [User email]
  var sDate = [Date opened] - WEEKDAY([Date opened], 3)
  var eDate = sDate + 7
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Voice'),
      FILTER('Voice', 
        NOT(ISBLANK([User email])) &&
        [User email] = thisEmail &&
        sDate <= [Date opened] && [Date opened] <= eDate
      )
    )


ive swapped the weekday 3 for a 1 and the number of interactions in a week works perfectly. Thanks :D
